# Prestahop Theme Development

Tags: css, themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have to convert an HTML design into Presta Theme, so where can I find a blank(neutral) theme like the ones used for Drupal and Wordpress. I searched but I haven't found anything that could help me. Any link to a tutorial or the link to the theme download would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually recommended to copy the **default-bootstrap** theme and apply your styles to it. A lot of modules and plugins depend on the HTML and JavaScript provided in the default theme, so writing your own theme would break all that.

Also, the default theme contains **a lot** of JavaScript code that handles purchasing, cart, etc. YOu must preserve these functions. If you looked up custom PrestaShop themes, 99.9% of theme are just visually modified base theme (**default-bootstrap**). You can actually copy the default theme in the back office (giving it a new name).

Comment: Can you provide some sort of video tutorial on modifying the theme? That would be very helpful.